# python math domain errors in math.log function

Tags: python, math

I have to use Python `math.log(x)` function with values of **x** from (0, ..., 1). Sometimes x may be too close to zero, and Python gives me an error:

> ValueError: math domain error

How can I know, what is the domain of definition of `math.log` function?

Comment: Wonder why don't they just tell us in the error msg it can't do log(0)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As long as your input is within the half-open interval (0, 1] (not including 0), you are fine.  You can't be too close to zero:

```
>>> math.log(sys.float_info.min)
-708.3964185322641
```

So simply checking for exactly zero (maybe as the result of an underflow) should be enough, or alternatively catch the exception and handle it.

**EDIT**: This also holds for the denormal minimum floating point number:

```
>>> math.log(sys.float_info.min * sys.float_info.epsilon)
-744.4400719213812
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but while `sys.float_info.min=2.2250738585072014e-308`, I still can do `math.log(2e-318)` on my system (and get `-731.5289...` as an answer). What's up with that?

Comment: @Evert: That's a ["dnormal number"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number), and they can actually be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Ah, learned something. I suspected `epsilon` was involved, but I'm still surprised it actually throws a correct answer for `math.log(5e-324)`, even though it's an underflow. Time to read [Wikipedia on this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Answer (score 7):

You are going over the supported precision, use [Decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) class instead.

```
>>> from math import log
>>> from decimal import Decimal

>>> d = Decimal('1E-1024')
>>> log(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: math domain error
>>> d.ln()
Decimal('-2357.847135225902780434423250')
```