# Math Domain error on math.log

Tags: python, math, logarithm

I have tried already available solution but couldn't solve this problem.

original Code:

```
 prob = n / self.totaldocs # 0.7445791360764896
 self.classpriorprob[cls] = math.log(prob)
```

solution: (but I prefer to take common log)

```
prob = n / self.totaldocs
d = Decimal(prob) 
self.classpriorprob[cls] = d.ln()
```

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19095955): I tried to round the number to 3 decimal places.

```
prob = n / self.totaldocs
number = round(prob, 3) # 0.744
self.classpriorprob[cls] = math.log(number)
```

but I am still getting math domain error.

**Edit**: I passed the value directly i.e. math.log(0.744) and it works. 
It also works when I try math.log() function in python console.

Please advise.

**Specs**:
python 3.6.3
pycharm

Comment: A math domain error normally occurs when you try to do a mathematically invalid operation, such as log(0) or log(-7). Are you sure that your code never tries to calculate an impossible value?

Comment: yes I am sure. variable prob is 0.7445791360764896. when I round it to 0.744 it still gives error. then i simply pass `0.744` i.e. math.log(0.744) and it works. It is very strange.

Comment: Are you passing a `Decimal` object to the log function? You may have to convert to `float` first.

Comment: I was not  passing a `Decimal` number. Anyway, I have answered the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting 0.0.

In my case, Solution is to skip 0.0 value.

```
if number > 0:
     self.classpriorprob[cls] = math.log(number)
```

Comment: It would be better to check  `if number > 0` both because the domain of `log` is positive and because checking for exact equality for floating point numbers is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the log sum exp trick:

```
 def findMaxArray(self,arr):
        maxValue = arr[0]
        for i in range(0, len(arr)):
            if(maxValue <arr[i]):
                maxValue = arr[i]
        return maxValue


    def logExpSum(self, arr ):
        #find maximum of array assuming the array passed is already containg log values
        maxVal =0
        maxVal= self.findMaxArray(arr)
        res = 0
        for i in range(0, len(arr)):
            res += math.exp (arr[i] - maxVal) 
        return (math.log(res)+ maxVal)
```